# Replacing some odd year values with NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset

| id | name | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 54132423 | (2021 FT1) | 2021 |
| 3733265 | (A911 VD2) | 911 |
| 2417217 | 417217 (6344 YS) | 6344 |
| 54111244 | (2021 CG3) | 2021 |
| 3798973 | (4788 BN6) | 4788 |

I want to replace some odd year values which I got after extracting them from the name column with NaN.

I've tried using

```
df.year.replace(['911', '4788', '6344'], np.nan)
```

but it's not working. Please help.

Comment: You're showing those as strings.  Are they strings or integers?  In either case, it doesn't matter.  `np.nan` is a floating point value.  You can't store a floating point value in a string OR an integer column.

Comment: You [shouldn't use an image here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).
What you have provided in your image can be represented as text formatted as code.
You can [edit] your post to make changes.

Comment: @TimRoberts they are strings. On converting them to integers it works but other year values now become floats which can't be converted to int due to the nan values now

Comment: @Tim you can have a NaN in a string column, also now pandas had non float NaNs ;)

Comment: @mozway are you referring to doing something like `.astype('Int32')` for the pandas dtype?

Comment: @BeRT2me you can read [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1/user_guide/integer_na.html)

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the year column has whitespaces to the right that's why my code wasn't working.

Comment: It's still easier to use a filtering function like my answer rather than picking each invalid year out yourself

Answer (score 0):

Some more information about your project might be helpful, since I imagine it would be easier to filter out invalid values when you parse them from the `name` column, rather than pulling everything over to the year column and then filtering the year column.

Regardless, here is a solution that should work. If the column is a string (which the comments suggest it is):

```
df.apply(lambda x: "" if (int(x["year"]) < 2022 && int(x["year"])) > 0 else x["year"] ,1)
```

This solution uses the pandas [apply function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), [python lambda functions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp), and [python ternary operators](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html) to condense the code. More adjustment might be necessary (to filter the years better), and it may be more readable to pull out the function into a real `def` block.